# Laravel mongodb search data in object

Tags: php, database, laravel, mongodb, nosql

I am building a Laravel app that connected with MongoDB. Now I am facing an issue when query data from the database.

```
table name: Employee    
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "user 1",
    "managers": [
      {
        "id": 321,
        "user_id": 1,
        "ack_groups: [
          ["2","3", "4"],
          ["2", "5", "6"]
        ]
      },
      ......
    ] 
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "user 2",
    "managers": [
      {
        "id": 3213,
        "user_id": 2,
        "ack_groups: [
          ["6","7", "8"],
          ["2", "5", "6"]
        ]
      },
      ......
    ] 
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "user 3",
    "managers": [
      {
        "id": 321,
        "user_id": 3,
        "ack_groups: [
          ["8","9", "14"],
          ["12", "15", "16"]
        ]
      },
      ......
    ] 
  },
]
```

I am trying to query list of employees data from Employee table with some conditions. The condition is that I want to get list of employees where `ac_groups` in `managers` equal to 2.
Then the output should be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "user 1",
    "managers": [
      {
        "id": 321,
        "user_id": 1,
        "ack_groups: [
          ["2","3", "4"],
          ["2", "5", "6"]
        ]
      },
      ......
    ] 
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "user 2",
    "managers": [
      {
        "id": 3213,
        "user_id": 2,
        "ack_groups: [
          ["6","7", "8"],
          ["2", "5", "6"]
        ]
      },
      ......
    ] 
  },
]
```

What I have tried in code: `Employee::where('verify_routes.managers.ack_groups', '=', "2")->get();`

Comment: its okey to do it with aggregate ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi can you show me how to do with aggregate? by doing raw query?

Comment: this is my aggregation in mongodb not laravel
https://mongoplayground.net/p/t5aI8Drpi6u

Answer (score 0):

[Forum: "Find in array value"](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/389#issuecomment-71288324)

[Doc: Specific Operators](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#mongodb-specific-operators)

This should work:

```php
Employee::where('verify_routes.managers.ack_groups', 'all', [2])->get();
```